# How to assign a number to return value of a function

Tags: haskell

The code below is to define the value of the given index in array, and I want if the index out of range, the return value assigned to 0:

```
cc::[a]->Int->a
cc [] b = 0
cc (x:xs) 0 = x
cc a b = cc (tail a) (b-1)
```

It causes an error:

```
* No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `0'
Possible fix:
     add (Num a) to the context of the type signature for:
         cc :: forall a. [a] -> Int -> a
* In the expression: 0
 In an equation for `cc': cc [] b = 0
```

Comment: This can only work if `a` is always of the same type as `0`. Consider using `Maybe a` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `0` is not possible because `0` is not always of type `a`.

However, you can return `Maybe a` instead:

```
cc :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
cc [] b = Nothing
cc (x:xs) 0 = Just x
cc a b = cc (tail a) (b-1)
```

Alternatively, if `a` is always of type `Int`, then you can change the signature:

```
cc :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
cc [] b = 0
cc (x:xs) 0 = x
cc a b = cc (tail a) (b-1)
```